# JS Date() required incorrect data to return correct result

Tags: javascript, date, cookies

I am creating a cookie that must "never" expire, although I am not sure if this is possible so, as a compromise, I have decided to set the "expires:" date to 2099/12/31 23:59:59.  However, to get this date, I need to set it as follows:

```
var killdate = new Date(2099, 11, 31, 23, 59, 59);
```

Now, unless I missed something, there is no 31 November so why would I have to set the date as such?

This is more a curiosity thing than a major issue with my code (although, I would like to make sure that I am not mucking anything up) but my online research hasn't been at all successful in clearing it up for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> **month**
>       Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.

Months run from 0-11, not 1-12. The date you're setting is, in fact, the 31st of December, 2099.

Comment: Ah, yes. Of course.  I didn't even think of that (which also explains why I was having no joy with online searches... I was searching in completely the wrong ballpark).  Thanks for the prompt response

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that some browsers have problems with dates past `2038` (when `unix epoch time` exceeds a `32-bit` `int`)

```
var killdate = new Date(2099, 11, 31, 23, 59, 59);
```

*Now, unless I missed something, there is no 31 November so why would I have to set the date as such*?

this is just future date used that is far enough from now. and in your example the date is actually  `31-Dec-2099 23:59:59` (month counts from 0 to 11)

Just for knowledge **AS of your curiosity**:

JS Date object was ported from Java 1.0, that's why. Inheriting all its flaws.

Everything but the day of the month is 0 based, [see here for a full list including ranges](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Comment: OK, but this should've been a comment rather than an answer since it doesn't attempt to answer the actual question about why December is 11.

Answer (score 0):

The days account for the longer days on any given month, not a specific one.

```
Max hours = 23
Max minutes = 59
Max seconds = 59
Max days = 31
Max months = 12
Max years = varies/changes
```

They never depend on each other. I think that if you're using UNIX timestamps they account for the days of the month.